# Синхронизировать действия на сервере и клиенте

Tags: node.js, сервер, синхронизация

Всем привет. Я делаю что-то типа небольшой игры, она достаточно динамическая, хоть и минималистичная. Я принимаю события от клиентов, потом двигаю все на сервере и рассылаю на клиенты как оно теперь все выглядит. Получается нормально, но в игре есть еще и механика выстрелов. И вот все это нормально работает, но потребляет очень много ресурсов сети. Я вынужден как-то экономить это. Я придумал такую штуку: персонажей я буду двигать как и раньше на сервере, но полет пуль я не буду каждый раз синхронизировать с сервером. Я просто один раз отдам событие, что кто-то выстрелил. А дальше каждый клиент пусть сам себе отрисовывает свои пульки, но считает попадание пулек пусть сервер. И это тоже здорово работает в плане экономии ресурсов. Но вот беда, пульки очень по разному летят на сервере и на клиенте. Дело в том, что я попытался синхронизировать всё через временную метку, на клиенте это Date.now() и на сервере тоже, я на ноде пишу. Так вот, а временные метки сильно отличаются, на пару секунд даже. Это не из-за задержки, разница прям очевидная. Это как так и почему? Есть ли какой-то таймер, которые даст точно время с точностью до секунды?
Ну или может я бред делаю, есть идеи получше?

Comment: Зачем вообще считывать время на клиенте? А если он Часы на год назад переведёт?

Comment: ну земля ему пухом, нечего часы переводить. Нет, ну а как тогда я могу заставить клиент и сервер делать что-то одновременно?

Comment: Есть такая игра (не реклама) War Thunder. Там используется аналогичный механизм взаимодействия с клиентом. Так вот, синхронизации времени вы никогда не получите. Единственный выход для вас - это корректировка результатов на основе временного лага передачи данных от клиента к серверу и наоборот.

Comment: Понял, ну а вот как быть с ситуацией когда с сервера было отправлено сообщение о выстреле, но оно по какой-то причине долго шло. И отрисовывать выстрел либо неактуально вообще, либо надо с середины пути его отрисовать? В варианте с привязкой ко времени я знал как это решить, но тут - нет

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, я кое-что придумал.
А что если сначала определить задержку - за сколько сообщение доходит от клиента к серверу.  Потом получить временную метку на клиенте и отправить сообщение на сервер, получить там временную метку и отправить ее на клиент. Потом на клиенте скорректировать временную метку сервера с учетом времени, которое сообщение шло до сервера и потом определить разницу временных меток сервера и клиента.

Ну а потом уже можно каждый раз получать временную метку на клиенте, корректировать ее с учетом того значения, которое мы получили на предыдущем шаге. Ну и у нас есть практически временная метка с сервера, хоть и с небольшой погрешностью.

Ну, вроде бы, это должно работать.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).